# Django Celery with RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django, django-celery, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to run task with Celery. I follow this tutorials [link](http://simondlr.com/post/24479818721/basic-django-celery-and-rabbitmq-example)

Everything has been setup successfully. The thing now is that I don't know how to execute a task. I run celeryd and it couldn't find the task.
I want to know what exactly I need to call to execute the task and how I need to config the task on RabbitMQ server, django-admin..
I cannot find any full tutorials about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Django by example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YSIL51S) has a full section on using Celery with RabbitMQ. There are also free tutorials or articles on this topic

- [How to install Celery on Django and Create a Periodic Task](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/02/how-to-install-celery-on-django-and.html)
- [Django Celery Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZQtMPMeT8c)
- [Django Celery Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpoSipgkYCQ)

Answer (score 2):

task definition
app/tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(param1,param2)
  print("task")
```

task execution:

```
from celery import current_app
current_app.send_task("app.tasks.add", ["param1", "param2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get an idea how to run Celery.

It worked fine for me.

http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2012/01/27/processing-long-running-django-tasks-using-celery-rabbitmq-supervisord-monit/